# Problems Installing mongodb pecl package: /tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, docker-image

I am building a custom mdocker image bases on (FROM) `php:7.0-fpm-alpine` image and I need to install the mongodb extention so my Dockerfile has the following content

```js
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine
MAINTAINER John Doe <jdoe@example.com>    

RUN apk update &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build_deps gcc g++ autoconf make openssl-dev pcre-dev &&\
    docker-php-source extract &&\
    pecl install mongodb && \
    docker-php-ext-enable mongodb && \
    docker-php-source delete && \
    apk del build_deps autoconf gcc g++ make && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*
```

But when I build the following image above I get the following output (output from alpine package installs have been ommited):

```
downloading mongodb-1.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download mongodb-1.3.0.tgz (927,842 bytes)
.........................................................................................................................................................................................done: 927,842 bytes
417 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserfgCbfi/mongodb-1.3.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
expr: syntax error
sh: 0: unknown operand
expr: syntax error
sh: 0: unknown operand
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable mongodb support... yes, shared
checking OpenSSL dir for mongodb... yes
checking whether to use system default cipher list instead of hardcoded value... no
checking PHP version... 70022
/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config' failed
Removing intermediate container 288e5589f2ca
```

Which as you can see I get the following error:

> ```
> /tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure: ./configure.lineno: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
> ```

So do you fellows have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is a newly introduced bug, there's a ticket opened for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPC-1014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that whoever wrote the pecl script for mongodb tested it on bash and not on `sh`. So the script is not compatible with sh. Solution is simple, run it through bash

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm-alpine
MAINTAINER John Doe <jdoe@example.com>

RUN apk update &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build_deps bash gcc g++ autoconf make openssl-dev pcre-dev &&\
    docker-php-source extract &&\
    /bin/bash -lc "pecl install mongodb" && \
    docker-php-ext-enable mongodb && \
    docker-php-source delete && \
    apk del build_deps && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Also for `apk del` you just need to give the virtual packages name